# New Twitter not working on chrome beta

Tags: google-chrome, twitter

New Twitter website isnt working properly on my google chrome 8.0.552.28 beta

When clicking on a tweet, it wont show the window with all the info. but the > button does change to < position, once like that it wont change back

Anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So I disabled extensions and it worked, then I enabled them again and it still works...

weird

Answer (score 1):

New Twitter works fine for me in the latest canary. It's probably an extension problem. I had something similiar, JS Bin did not work properly on every second reload. A bookmarklet caused this, it was auto-loaded on every page with *Personalized Web* (it's like Greasemonkey for Firefox).